# date comparison with strftime in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I'm comparing a unix timestamp in microseconds and a time with strftime. To do so I need to use a common unit. I don't understand why it works in microseconds (ie by multiplying strftime by 1 million) but not the other way around.

```
SELECT

strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00") AS Apr1st,
1492605353892000/1000000 as d,

strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00")*1000000 As Apr1st_us,
1492605353892000 AS d_us,

1492605353892000/1000000 > strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00") AS cmp,
1492605353892000/1000000 - strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00") AS diff,

1492605353892000 > strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00")*1000000 AS cmp_us,
1492605353892000 - strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00")*1000000 AS diff_us

;
```

which gives me:

```
|     Apr1st |          d |        Apr1st_us |             d_us | cmp |    diff | cmp_us |       diff_us |
|------------|------------|------------------|------------------|-----|---------|--------|---------------|
| 1491004800 | 1492605353 | 1491004800000000 | 1492605353892000 |   0 | 1600553 |      1 | 1600553892000 |
```

Answer (score 1):

`strftime` returns an string, so when comparing with an integer, [the integer is always less](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order). The version with `strftime(...)*1000000` works because the multiplication converts it to an integer, allowing the comparison to work on numbers.

Casting `strftime` return value makes it right:

```
1492605353892000/1000000 > CAST(strftime("%s", "2017-04-01 00:00:00") AS INT)
```

Comment: Thank you, I really struggled for 40min before finding out what was the problem.